# How to extract the Subject Alternative Name from a CSR by just using the openssl command?

Tags: command-line, unix, openssl

I would need to extract the Subject Alternative Name from a CSR. Is there any way I can extract this other than using the "-text" in openssl req -in test.csr -text -noout? (Maybe similar with the -subject parameter?)

Currently, this is the command I'm using to get the SubjAltName:

```
openssl req -in test.csr -text -noout | grep DNS
```

I noticed that the SAN is sometimes formatted as "email" or probably other type and so grep DNS doesn't work dynamic. Is there any command you can recommend which will work to get the SubjAltName correctly?